# How to do this: After every space key press, create a new span element and put caret there?

Tags: javascript

How to put the cursor on a div and a certain position of that div.

Try to put it with setStar but the cursor is located at the beginning and I do not want

the error is:  `{"message": "Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'setStart' on 'Range': There is no child at offset}`

```js
let written = '';

document.getElementById('parent').addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  var palabra = written;
  written += String.fromCharCode(e.which);

  if (e.which === 32) {
    var element = document.getElementById("parent");
    var doc = element.ownerDocument || element.document;

    var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
    // seleccionamos el nodo activo
    var sel = window.getSelection();

    if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
      var range = win.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
      const index = range.startOffset;
      // range.setStart(document.getElementById(window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode.id), index);
    }
    sel.focusNode.textContent = sel.focusNode.textContent.replace(palabra, "");
   
  }
})
```

```css
#parent>div {
  border-color: yellow;
  float: left;
}

.root {
  padding-right: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" contenteditable=true style="border: black 2px solid; height:200px">
  <div class="root" id="1">Que</div>
  <div class="root" id="2">word</div>
  <div class="root" id="3">Lorem</div>
  <div class="root" id="4">Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

I want to put in the node `document.getElementById(window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode.id)`

and your position of node is saved in the variable `index`

**Example:**

When I type 'hi' and I press spacebar should this be the result

[image]

Comment: @DineshGhule i make a spellcheker to chat

Comment: do you mean how to move the cursor?

Comment: @SheshankS. yes exactitly, i want move to a determinated index

Comment: Alright checkout my answer @x-rw

Comment: what do you mean by index? do you mean position?

Comment: Why are you using keypress event? It simply work well

Comment: @x-rw please see my updated answer it should help you more sorry i didn't understand your question your clarifications helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the result of a while of research and coding, hope it helps you :)

For other people: I changed the `<div>` to `<span>` after  confirming with the question asker if it was okay.

```js
var newString = "";

document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
  newString += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
    var targetelement = parent.childNodes[parent.childNodes.length - 1];
    var div = document.createElement("SPAN");
    div.className = "root";
    div.id = parseInt(document.getElementsByClassName("root")[document.getElementsByClassName("root").length - 1].id) + 1;
    div.contenteditable = false;
    div.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
    var beforeelement = parent.childNodes[parent.childNodes.length - 1];
    beforeelement.innerHTML = beforeelement.innerHTML.substring(0, 1) + beforeelement.innerHTML.substring(1).replace('&nbsp;', '');
    document.getElementById("parent").appendChild(div);
    console.log("appended!");


    var selectionrange = document.createRange();
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    selectionrange.setStart(targetelement, 1);
    selectionrange.collapse(true);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(selectionrange);
  }
}
```

```css
#parent>div {
  border-color: yellow;
  float: left;
}

.root {
  padding-right: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" contenteditable=true style="border: black 2px solid; height:200px">
  <span class="root" id="1">Que</span>
  <span class="root" id="2">word</span>
  <span class="root" id="3">Lorem</span>
  <span class="root" id="4">Ipsum</span>
  <span class="root" id="5"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: check my code and you'll see if you can move, but not how I want it

Comment: @x-rw sorry i don't understand what you are saying.. the problem is you can't move the cursor, you can't do it with js

Comment: @x-rw If this helped you please mark it as the correct answer. you can't move the cursor with javascript

Comment: cursor of mouse?

Comment: @SheshankS. Changing the base HTML to an `input` where the OP has used a `contenteditable` is just wrong. That decision lies solely in the hands of the OP. I won't even get into how you copy pasted what I had previously written.

Comment: @SheshankS. 
the  problem is that I'm working with div instead of a plain text

Comment: @x-rw I think i did it, please see my answer

Comment: your code selects everything, I do not want that, check the image of my question please

Comment: @x-rw ?? everything is highlighted in your code though.... can you explain in words what it should do then, sorry but your screenshot shows everything highlighted

Comment: @x-rw okay so after you type in hi, in the text `QuewordLoremIpsum`, it then becomes this after a space`QuewordLorhi emIpsum`, then what text gets highlighted?

Comment: I just need the cursor to appear as in my image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174205/discussion-between-sheshank-s-and-x-rw).

Answer (score -1):

Ok so I'm gonna assume you want to move the caret (the caret is the blinking line that denotes where you start editing text) and not the mouse pointer (since that is impossible).

This will change the Caret position to wherever you want in your text:

```
element.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
```

Which is a hack based off of selecting text from the desired posistion to the same position which basically moves the caret there.

**UPDATE :**

OK so some research later it looks like this only works with `input` type of elements and `contentditable` fields work differently. Anyway, this is some code that I have tested and will work in your case

```
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
var range = document.createRange();
var selection = window.getSelection();
var element = parent.childNodes[parent.childNodes.length - 1];
range.setStart(element, offset);
range.collapse(true);
selection.removeAllRanges();
selection.addRange(range);
```

Comment: You can test with my example please

Comment: @x-rw to be honest I'm not sure **exactly** where you want to put the caret. But, this code does seem to be selecting the last child in your list of text divs, and then setting the caret at the offset (which I hardcoded to 1 for testing) I want it to.

Comment: the problem is the line  sel.focusNode.textContent = sel.focusNode.textContent.replace(palabra, ""); 
and then I create a new div with that content

Comment: the other problem is that I'm working with div instead of a plain text

Comment: @x-rw could you explain what you want your code to accomplish?...some of the code you've written is rather twisted for example `document.getElementById(window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode.id` is redundant since it is the same as `window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode`. What is this code supposed to be doing? on pressing space you need to set the caret to a particular position and then what?

Comment: OK so I tested the current code with the changes I made and it looks like it does what you want. Test the code with `offset = 0` and confirm if this is what you are attempting to do.

Comment: the cursor should be placed as in the image the red bar

Comment: @x-rw This comment discussion is already long enough.so I'll make a few final points..One, the original question, how to move the caret to a particular position has been answered, debugging your entire codebase is not in the scope of an SO question. Second, I see no red bar, it is probably part of the rest of your project and as mentioned previously, not part of the question...Please spend some time, debug your code, and if you face any issues you are unable to overcome, the SO community will be glad to help you. Cheers :D