# How can I put individual words in <span> elements in a contenteditable <div>?

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

### question

How do I put words in `<span>` elements in a contenteditable `<div>` while still keeping the cursor position? For example: if someone typed:
"the fox guy jumped over the dog", it would output:

```html
<span>the</span> <span>fox</span> <span>guy</span>...
```

### attempt

```js
document.querySelector("#container").addEventListener("input", function() {
    this.innerHTML = "<span>" + this.innerText
        .replaceAll("&", "&amp;") //escape HTML
        .replaceAll("<", "&lt;")
        .replaceAll(">", "&gt;")
        .split(" ")
        .join("</span><span>") + "</span>";
});
```

It didn't work because it didn't keep the cursor position, it just teleported the cursor to the end.

### UPDATE:

I want to use the `input` event because I want it to split *while* the person is typing, and not when they click out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do this: After every space key press, create a new span element and put caret there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51111891/how-to-do-this-after-every-space-key-press-create-a-new-span-element-and-put-c)

Comment: what's the purpose?

Comment: What should happen if you press spacebar many times?